# Excel VBA - Import textfile with UTF 8 encoding

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to import TXT files into my excel workbook but am experience conversion errors when the data includes chinese / japanese / korean characters.

How can I import the textfile with UTF-8 encoding to ensure the characters are displayed correctly?

```
' Set default path to pick files
    IntPath = ""
    Set pickf = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

' Set detail options for selection window
    With pickf
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails:
        .InitialFileName = IntPath:
        .Filters.Clear:
        .Filters.Add "Textfile", "*.txt", 1:
        .ButtonName = "Import":
        .Title = "Select textfile for import"

' if nothing selected, close
        If .Show = -1 Then
            project = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

' speed up, unhide all report sheets and clear content
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

' import textfile into temp sheet
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & project, Destination:=Sheets("Opera Data").Range("A2"))
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

i'am importing csv file and i have encountered same problem as well and i just solved the problem by defining

```
 .TextFilePlatform = 65001
```

at here like this

```
        .
        .
        .
' import textfile into temp sheet
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & project, Destination:=Sheets("Opera Data").Range("A2"))
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001 ' here you can put here What characterset you want.
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

also i have taken this from here. it may help
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/open-csv-utf-8-files-no-acces-to-editing-bom.36165/